# String calling jlabel gives a error The method setBackground(Color) is undefined for the type String

Tags: java

I'm working on this bingo game, and i got jlabel set for the balls table, i random the number and add the letters according to its range, in the if statement i unify letter and number to call the jlabel to change background of sort balls and present the number in the screen as well. but when i set the background it gives me a error.

I think the problem is the letter+number, should be converted to something else other than string, but i dont know how to do it.try parseChar parseString and nothing.

```
JLabel b5 = new JLabel("B5"); // example

play(){
Random rnd = new Random(); 
        int bolas = rnd.nextInt(75)+1; 
if (board[bolas] == 0){  
                   if(bolas == 0) { 
                       play(); 
                   }else if(bolas == 1 && bolas <= 15) {
                       letra = "b";
                       numero = bolas;
                   }else if(bolas >= 16 && bolas <= 30) {
                       letra = "i";
                       numero = bolas;
                   }else if(bolas >= 31 && bolas <= 45) {
                       letra = "n";
                       numero = bolas;
                   }else if(bolas >= 46 && bolas <= 60) {
                       letra = "g";
                       numero = bolas;
                   }else if(bolas >= 61 && bolas <= 75) {
                       letra = "o";
                       numero = bolas;
                   }  
                   board[bolas] = bolas; 
                   if(gameRunning == true) {
                       bolaSorteadaText.setText(letra+numero);
                       (letra+numero).setBackground(new Color(0x00aa00));// error:The method setBackground(Color) is undefined for the type String
                       System.out.println("Bola sorteada: "+board[bolas] );
                       }else {
                           bolaSorteadaText.setText("A0"); 
                       }
```

Comment: Rather than create a random number, create an int array of 75 numbers from 1 - 75 and shuffle the array.  The ball number should be sufficient for your internal model, while you need the letter for display.

Comment: Try `bolaSorteadaText.setBackground`.

Comment: everything works, except for the part that i want to color the last called ball, if i call the jlabel b5.setbackground(new Color(0x00aa00); it works, but i want the label name to be generated when the ball is called. is there a way to make it work?

Comment: k314159 i got a jlabels representing the balls from 1 to 75, those jlabel its like, b1 to b15, and i need those background changed when their respective numbers are called. the random gives me the jlabel name that i need to change but it is a string, and need to be called the jlabel name instead. It is like, after the random generates and if statement process, i guess i receiving the name like this "b5".setBackground() instead of b5.setBackground()